# Glycogenolysis & Gluconeogenesis

Tags: metabolism, endocrinology, glucose

Is glycogenolysis and Gluconeogenesis is the same in the terms of product formed?

This doubt arrived when I was attempting true & false and the question was

*Glucocorticoids stimulate glycogenolysis, lipolysis and proteolysis*

The answer given was *false because "Glucocorticoids stimulate **gluconeogenesis**, lipolysis and proteolysis"*

Comment: Obviously not from the feedback you received. Have you done an Internet search or consulted Wikipedia. Please do that before posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome A learner,

**Glycogenolysis** is the breakdown of the molecule glycogen into glucose.

**Gluconeogenesis** is the metabolic process by which organisms produce glucose and other sugars from non-carbohydrate precursors.

These processes arrive at the same product (Glucose).

*Glucocorticoids* stimulate the process of *Gluconeogenesis* but not the process of *Glycogenolysis*.

To elaborate...

[Glucocorticoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glucocorticoid) are steroid hormones that stimulate production of glucose in the liver via *Gluconeogenesis*. But Glucocorticoids are not involved in the pathway of *Glycogenolysis*.

Therefore: *Glucocorticoids **do not** stimulate glycogenolysis, lipolysis and proteolysis.*

And the answer is *false*.